# Google sheets, count how many times a specific value is present with a specific condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am sure the question has been answered many times but I do not know how to search for it.

I have a table in google sheets

Colum A, Names: Anna, Tim, Richard
Colum B, what did they eat Apples, Pear, Banana

So I have this table now

A,B

Anna,Pear

Richard,Pear

Tim,Apple

Anna,Pear

Richard,Banana

Anna,Bannana

I need a formula to count how many times Anna ate pears.

thank you very much in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(A:B; "select count(A) where A = 'Anna' and B = 'Pear'"); 2)
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(A:A&B:B; "AnnaPear"))
```

[image]